# German grammar and sentence structure

Tags: word-order

Example sentence:

> You will be given access to the folder
>
> Du wirst zugang zur ordner gegeben werden

Is das richtig?

Translation software always misses the werden at the end, which in my opinion changes the meaning.

Also can I know how often future perfect (will have/will have been) used in spoken German?

I know the conjunctive II is often used. But the above ones, are they used often?

Comment: There is no future perfect in the original sentence - the perfect participle ("given") is there because it's a passive sentence. This sentence cannot be translated literally because in German the dative has to be used here, and the dative must be preserved in the passive voice, as mentioned by c.p.

Answer (score 2):

Die Übersetzung ist nicht richtig. Für das Personalpronomen und den Ordner musst du den Dativ verwenden. Außerdem sind *Zugang* und *Ordner* Substantive, die man groß schreibt:

> Dir wird Zugang zum Ordner gegeben werden.

Das Ganze klingt ein wenig gestelzt bzw. unnötig kompliziert. Ich würde eher

> Du erhältst Zugang zum Ordner.

verwenden.

Comment: Man sollte hier keine Hausaufgabe lösen. Auch ist diese Seite weder für Übersetzungen noch für Korrekturlesen.

Answer (score 0):

It's not right.

*Dir*, not *du*. After making the passive voice, dative remains dative. The first question to you is: why is dative? The second question to you is, after you correct this, which changes the subject, you have to change the conjugation of the (first) *werden*.

With this information you should able to construct the right sentence. Good luck!

(The second part of the question is ignored, for one poses here only one question per post).